# Create JavaPairRDD from a collection with a custom partitioner

Tags: apache-spark, partitioning, rdd

Is it possible to create a `JavaPairRDD<K,V>` from a `List<Tuple2<K,V>>` with a specified partitioner? the method `parallelizePairs` in JavaSparkContext only takes the number of slices and does not allow using a custom partitioner. Invoking `partitionBy(...)` results in a shuffle which I would like to avoid.

Why do I need this? let's say I have `rdd1` of some type `JavaPairRDD<K,V>` which is partitioned according to the hashCode of `K`. Now, I would like to create `rdd2` of another type `JavaPairRDD<K,U>` from a `List<Tuple2<K,U>>` in order to finally obtain `rdd3 = rdd1.join(rdd2).mapValues(...)`. If `rdd2` is not partitioned the same way `rdd1` is, the `cogroup` call in `join` will result in expensive data movement across the machines. Calling `rdd2.partitionBy(rdd1.partitioner())` does not help either since it also invokes shuffle. Therefore, it seems like the only remedy is to ensure `rdd2` is created with the same partitioner as `rdd1` to begin with. Any suggestions?

ps. If `List<Tuple2<K,U>>` is small, another option is broadcast hash joins, i.e. making a `HashMap<K,U>` from `List<Tuple2<K,U>>`, broadcasting it to all partitions of `rdd1`, and performing a map-side joining. This turns out to be faster than repartitioning `rdd2`, however, it is not an ideal solution.